# No such file or directory error (python)

Tags: python, html-parsing, os.path

In my code I've set the path for the txt file to the script path, but for some reason after the program writes some txt files for a few of the links, it throws this error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" I don't really understand why for some of the links it works, but for others it can't seem to find the directory.

```
from lxml import html
import requests, os.path
spath = os.path.dirname(__file__)  ## finds path of script
main_pg = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/") ## input site here
with open(os.path.join(spath, "Main.txt"),"w", encoding='utf-8') as doc: 
    doc.write(main_pg.text)
tree = html.fromstring(main_pg.content)
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "http:") or starts-with(@href,"https:") or starts-with(@href,"ftp:")]/@href')  ## To avoid non-absolute hrefs
for href in hrefs:
    link_pg = requests.get(href)
    tree2 = html.fromstring(link_pg.content)
    doc_title = tree2.xpath('//html/head/title/text()')  ## selects title of text from each link
    with open(os.path.join(spath, "%s.txt"%doc_title), "w", encoding ='utf-8') as href_doc:
        href_doc.write(link_pg.text)
```

Comment: Use rather `spath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`

Comment: Which file isn't it finding? What is the directory? What is the file? Does the `doc_title` contain characters invalid on windows?

Comment: For example on the main New York Times webpage it throws this error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "['Hereâ\\x80\\x99s What You Missed in the Debate - The New York Times'].txt"", but for some reason it can create txt docs for other links, just not this one. Also SIslam, I tried changing the dirname and still got the same error.

Comment: Tried updated script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there exist several errors- BTW you need to sanitize your file name before use it as a name. `doc_title` return a list so as filename it is invalid so use `join` function to get string from the list. After getting string from the list remove invalid filename char from it and use as filename.

Try below (python 2.7)-

```
import os,sys,codecs
from lxml import html
import requests, os.path,re
spath = os.path.dirname(__file__)  ## finds path of script
#spath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])## or use this
main_pg = requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com/") ## input site here
with codecs.open(os.path.join(spath, "Main.txt"),"w", encoding='utf-8') as doc: 
    doc.write(main_pg.text)
tree = html.fromstring(main_pg.content)
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "http:") or starts-with(@href,"https:") or starts-with(@href,"ftp:")]/@href')  ## To avoid non-absolute hrefs
for href in hrefs:
    link_pg = requests.get(href)
    tree2 = html.fromstring(link_pg.content)
    doc_title = tree2.xpath('//html/head/title/text()')  ## selects title of text from each link
    # Now remove invalid characters from the file name - for invalid chars see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved%5Fcharacters%5Fand%5Fwords
    file_name = re.sub(ur'(\?|\\|\?|\%|\*|:\||"|<|>)',ur'',''.join(doc_title))
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(spath, "%s.txt"%file_name), "w", encoding ='utf-8') as href_doc:
        href_doc.write(link_pg.text)
```

I just used `regex` to remove invalid filename chars, you can use `replace` function- for details of the regex i used see- <kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aK7mD6/1)</kbd>

Comment: Cool, I got it working! Thanks! I was just looking up all the things you added, and I'm curious, in python 3 and above is codecs.open obsolete? It seems that in py3 open has the same capabilities.